# What is returned when I count nulls?

Tags: sql

IF I have a table:

```
ID |field|
1  |     |
2  |     |
3  |     |
```

All the field records are null. I want to know what is returned when I query:

```
SELECT Count(field)
FROM table
```

### EDIT

I want to know what to expect on various emplementations that use sql. Since I don't have access to other implementations, besides Access, I cannot check myself, but it is important for me to know this. The Count query is just an example to show how that implementation treats the null values. Please don't show me any workarounds, how to count nulls, or how to ignore nulls. Just answer what will happen when I do. Thank you.

Comment: why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too specific to be of use to others. It's also very simple to test simply by running the query provided in the question.

Comment: This ain't so bad. The behaviour might be implementation-specific.

Comment: If only there was some way to execute SQL code and find out...

Comment: Ironically, the sample query doesn't count `NULL` values.  It counts non-`NULL` values.  The OP seems quite confused.

Comment: As an aside, a) always include your DBMS with SQL questions as some things may vary by vendor b) it helps to include what you have already tried. For example, if you ran the query above but did not understand the results ie *".. I tried running this query. It returned result X ... but I am confused because I was actually expecting result Y. Can anyone explain?"*

Comment: I want to know what will happen in different implementations that use sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is use a `conditional SUM`

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numNULL,
     SUM(CASE WHEN field IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as numNOT_NULL,
FROM table
```

**EDIT**

Sorry if i missunderstand your question. But your comment is very different to you original question.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

> SQL COUNT(column_name) Syntax 
>  The COUNT(column_name) function returns
>   the number of values `(NULL values will not be counted)` of the
>   specified column:

In all plataform `COUNT()` should be 0.

You can use sqlFiddle to test your query in different database (MySql, SqlLite, MSSQL, Postgre, Oracle). Use the function `Text to DDL` to create the table very easy. Take consideration sometimes the site have some timeout so maybe need to try later

Here is mySQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/413ea7/1

Comment: I don't want to do a count, as in "how many nulls are there?". I want to know **what happens** when I do a regular count in different implementations that use sql.

Comment: well as you can see for my answer, exists this workaround because `COUNT` doesnt consider null

Comment: Again, I want to to know **what happens** when I do a **regular count** , just like in my question, on different implementations that use sql. I don't want a workaround, I just want to know what to expect on MySQL, oracle, etc. (right now I'm using access, and can't use CASE at all.) As I don't have all these implementations, I cannot check myself.

Comment: I update my answer with more information, hope that help